# What is the meaning of “course of nature” in James 3:6?

Tags: james, terminology

> "And the tongue is a fire, a world of iniquity: so is the tongue among
> our members, that it defileth the whole body, and setteth on fire the
> course of nature; and it is set on fire of hell." KJV

Newer translations speak of "the course of his life" or "your whole life".

A very similar question asked 3 years ago included the phrase "wheel of birth" as if that was what could be meant. But I cannot get this question to come up, even though someone answered it very recently. So, if anyone has heard of reasons why 'course of nature' could be understood as 'wheel of birth' I would be interested, as that latter phrase seems to be of a Buddhist / Hindu origin, and not a biblical one. And, of course, I am keen to get a Christian view on this text.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34319/what-is-the-meaning-of-course-of-nature-wheel-of-birth-in-james-36-kjv